# Oracle licensing and pricing

Tags: licensing, oracle-11g

Question: I'd like to download Oracle 11g database for evaluation purposes.

Now I found this link for downloads:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

But it says one must register 'for accessing premium contents'.
But in the same time, it looks like one can download the full database for free.

But surely, Oracle doesn't give it for free, but in the registration, there's no mention of any cost/fees, or any billing address.

Is this registration free, or as 'premium' suggests, will you get a bill for it if you do (supposed you enter true data)?

Or how does Oracle handle licensing/payment? I can not see any price tag there anywhere, nor any information on it on that registration page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download and use Oracle free of charge according to the OTN license. Read the license carefully. Once your needs move beyond those scoped in the OTN license you must purchase an OPN license.

Comment: One more license that's no more than a disclaimer & an empty threat against pirating, but unlike others, it's clear and precise. I admit, I've made it a bad habit to not usually read them anymore. Silly silly, they reserve the right to investigate the use of the database - wonder how they want to legally do that - short of a legally obtained search warrant.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you won't get patches for the OTN download. If you want patches, you'll need a valid support contract. If you want help when your database server goes belly up and the disks get corrupted, then that's where support comes in.

Secondly, OTN membership gives you access to the forums. useful but no substitute for support when the sh*t hits the fan.

Thirdly, there is an option in the database install for it to connect your Oracle support account.

Finally, shop.oracle.com is the easiest way to see the prices. If you buy big, you can probably negotiate a better deal with your local Oracle sales team or reseller.

Comment: I would go further to say only use shop.oracle.com for estimating cost in a worst case scenario. If you're actually serious about purchasing get in touch with an Oracle rep. You'll get major discounts off the prices listed there.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Technology Network registration is free. You can download and install the Oracle database for free as long as it is for non-production use. I suggest you read the [Oracle Technology Network Developer License](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html).

Comment: That's not true. You can only use it free for development, demo or testing before bringing your app prod. However if your application ever becomes production then all dev/demo/testing must be licensed properly according to the OPN. Once you're an OPN member you do not qualify for OTN licensing.